# NameError: global name 'ERROR_DEFS' is not defined

Tags: python

I am new to python

[This](https://github.com/Xilinx/u-boot-xlnx/blob/master-next/tools/zynq-boot-bin.py) is the python script I am trying to execute:

```
[root@xilinx tools]# ./zynq-boot-bin.py
test.py -u <inputfile> -o <outputfile>


[root@xilinx tools]# ./zynq-boot-bin.py -u u-boot-spl -o BOOT.BIN
Input file is: u-boot-spl
Output file is: BOOT.BIN
Using /home/Hannan/master-next/u-boot-xlnx/tools/u-boot-spl to get image length - it is 470104 (0x72c58) bytes
Loaded to the OCM image should fit into 3 mapped pages of OCM - 192K (0x30000), specified  0x72c58
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./zynq-boot-bin.py", line 217, in <module>
    0) #start_exec)
  File "./zynq-boot-bin.py", line 132, in image_generator
    exit (ERROR_DEFS['HEAD'])
NameError: global name 'ERROR_DEFS' is not defined
[root@xilinx tools]#
```

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: The script is looking for a dictionary called `ERROR_DEFS`. Quick glance at the script you provided shows that there is no such dictionary in the code.

Comment: Did you write this code?

Comment: If that’s not your code, bring it up the author.

Comment: @Wooble no I have not written, I am just using it

Comment: Well, it was clearly slapped together and not tested. The indentation is also all over the place, and there's an `exit` that does nothing at all in there for no apparent reason.

Comment: It states in the comments block as:  `Hack origin version and just take the part which generate boot.bin for U-BOOT SPL`.Probably untested code with errors and missing variables/functions.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is very simple and is already stated in the error trace.

The variable 'ERROR_DEFS' is in your code used, but not declared/set up.